# How to get data from the previous month result in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 tables `ms` and `fr`.

`ms` contains columns `pid,month`, and `totalsales`, while `fr` contains `pid, month`, and `forecast`.

In both tables, each `pid` has 12 record based on month.

I actually want to calculate the demand where the formula is `(0.3 * totalsales) + (0.7 * previous month result of forecast)`. The previous month result of forecast is like when the user choose `pid` 2 and `month` 2, then it will take the forecast result from month 1 as its calculation data.

I tried it already but the desired result is not returned:

```
select 
    ((0.3 * totalsalesamount) + (0.7 * forecastdemand)) as demand 
from 
    Monthlysales, forecastreorder 
where 
    Monthlysales.P_ID = forecastreorder.Productid 
    and Monthlysales.P_ID = 1 
    and forecastreorder.Month = 2
```

When I execute the code above the result is based on their each `forecast` result. For example, when I choose `pid` 1, `month` 2, then it will take the `forecast` result from `month` 2 also. meanwhile i want it to take the `forecast` result from `month` 1 as its calculation data.

Comment: This isn't very clear.  Perhaps some sample data and sample results (both actual and expected) would help clarify.

Comment: And also specify what happend on month 1,must get data from previous year?

Comment: for example,totalsales amount for pid1,month1  = 100, then for pid1, month 1, the forecastdemand = 100, pid1,month2, forecastdemand=0 then if i want to calculate the forecast for pid1,month2 then the calculation become ((0.3*100)+(0.7*100)). But when i execute the code above, the calculation become ((0.3*100) +(0.7*0))

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get previous month in sql

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar table but with a year field, using `ISNULL` for no found data from previous moth, presume the previous is the month sales.

```
SELECT    
   0.3 * ms.totalsalesamount + 0.7 * ISNULL(fr.forecastdemand, ms.totalsalesamount) as demand
FROM            
   ms 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   fr ON ms.pid = fr.pid 
      AND fr.month = CASE WHEN ms.month > 1 THEN ms.month - 1 ELSE 12 END 
      AND fr.year = CASE WHEN ms.month > 1 THEN ms.year ELSE ms.year - 1 END
```

Comment: actually im not inserting the month value with the actual date form. i just insert 1-12 inside it. how can i do it if i input the month value like that?? @@

Comment: Then not be able to process correctly when the month is 1, it would be wrong to compare it with the 12. 
Change the line of the month 
AND fr.month = ms.month - 1  
and remove the line that refers to the year, then the month 1 is like no data found for previous month, because you dont hava any 0 value in month field